# How do I remove a tube from a compression coupler?

Tags: irrigation

I have a half-inch compression end cap attached to some half-inch tubing. The compression end cap is similar to this one: http://www.homedepot.com/p/DIG-1-2-in-Compression-End-Cap-Q58/100125237

I haven't been able to work out how to get the tubing out of this so I can reuse it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

If you wiggle the fitting from side to side while pulling, you can get it to step itself off the irrigation tube. This works for all sizes of these type push-in drip irrigation compression fittings.

The tube itself might not reseal if you push another fitting on, but the fix is simple for the tube, cut off the marred surface or push on a little further.

The fitting is made of harder plastic than the Polyethylene tube or dripline so it comes out of the equation pretty unscathed and reusable.

Answer (score 2):

Soak the connecting points in a big pot of boiling water. I did it right on the stove. Then pull with pliers. It worked for me. Pull hard and maybe re-soak after it budges a bit to finish getting it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to lose some of the length of the tubing, remove the screw on cap and cut the tubing and then push it through and out the end where the cap was.

If you don't have the luxury of removing a cap, then either of the above methods work - or you can cut the tubing and then grab it with a pair of needle nose pliers (with one side in the tubing and the other outside) and twist the pliers to wrap the tubing around them - this reduces the diameter and lets you pull out the tubing.

Answer (score 1):

To remove without cutting the tubing if you can't lose the length:

1. Place a hose clamp over the poly tubing as close as possible to the compression fitting.
2. Tighten the hose clamp until the diameter of the poly tube looks to be reduced about 25-30%
3. Twist and pull the poly tube out of the compression fitting.
4. Remove the hose clamp. Poly tubing should recover most of its original diameter unless the hose clamp was over-tightened. If too small, place something in the ID of the poly tubing to stretch it back open.

Answer (score 0):

Use needle nose pliers as shown in [video](https://www.google.com/search?q=How%20to%20reuse%20drip%20compression%20fittings&biw=1296&bih=695&sxsrf=APq-WBt6Ogcbw7Qid1x6FWU8Y8IvajY1wA%3A1647809296465&ei=EJM3YuCGHKaV0PEPvJa5kA0&ved=0ahUKEwjgzpf-x9X2AhWmCjQIHTxLDtIQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=How%20to%20reuse%20drip%20compression%20fittings&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIICCEQFhAdEB46BQgAEKIEOggIABAIEA0QHjoECCEQCkoECEEYAEoECEYYAFAAWLYjYM4laABwAXgAgAGFAogB6waSAQU4LjAuMZgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#kpvalbx=_jZM3YrP8IvOT0PEPlMWO6Ao32) below.

Recap:

1. Cut the connector from the tubing, but leave 3/4" of tubing protruding from the connector.
2. Work one side of the needle nose pliers between the outside of the tubing and inner side of the connector to fold the tubing lengthwise down so its cross-section is only half of the tubes original diameter (cross-section is now "U" shaped).
3. Now use the the full pliers to flatten the "U" sideways so now its width is only 1/4 of the original tubing cross-sectional circumference.
4. Wiggle the flattened piece of tubing out of the connector, trying to avoid catching it on the sharp interior edge "grip" ring(s).